# Why would greek gods allow other religions to take over?

Tags: religion, gods, secret-society

I am planning to write a story where greek gods exist. But I can't figure out a reason why they would allow other religions to take over and people to stop worshiping them. And I need this for my story to work because it is set in the XXI century and these days the majority of people doesn't believe in Greek gods.

Comment: In your story, is the history of religion just as it is in real life? If so you can read the history books and find out why Christianity ousted traditional beliefs all around the world. Are the GGs trying to make a comeback? If so then in fact  they *are* succeeding in Greece in the 21st century although there has been opposition from the Church.  https://www.theguardian.com/world/2006/may/05/greece

Comment: I feel this question needs some work: are the mythological Greel Gods the only Gods? What kind of answer are you looking for? Because, I can think of 4 or 5 reasons, all simingly equally valid. Are they still "alive"? Do you want to match our known history?

Comment: Unless you define criteria for evaluating the answers, there is no way to answer this in a objective way.

Comment: You need to establish rules of existence. If gods exist even when no one believes in them? why would gods need for humans to believe in them. Are gods need to be gods (i.e. Zeus prefer to be serial adulterer rather than wasting time on answering prayers)

Comment: They got bored of the game & took up a new hobby?

Comment: Check out the Mithermage books by Orson Scott Card. While he follows the Norse family, the Greeks play an important role too.

Comment: in your story do the gods gain anything from worship? if not I can't see any reason why they would care what us mortals worship

Comment: Religions (~ their officials) are terribly afraid of nonreligious people and atheism, because they all promise things that some "god" later has to keep, and fear to get exposed of this suspicous and possibly fraudulous behaviour. If I was an actual god, I would like atheists much better, but then I'm not. Hope I'm not insulting your Zeus by implying he might be no better than any pope. ;-)

Comment: Isn't this similar to the DC universe?

Answer (score 1):

There could be a couple reasons:

**1)** Arrogance: the gods may have believed in themselves so strongly that they humans to form other religions. They may have thought that even if the other religions were present, because they were the 'first', that people would still contiue to worship them.

**2)** Carelessness: they may have forgotten how quickly time passes for humans and so not checked in on them for a while. For them they may have checked on their worshipers 5 minutes ago but for humans this may have been 100 years for example.

**3)** Free will: humans have free will and so there may not have actually been anything that they could have done to prevent it.

**4)** Entertainment: The gods may have decided to let the humans create these new religions so that they could take on human forms and act as these new gods/ messangers of the new gods. For example Zeus may have taken on the human form of Jesus and thus by creating a new religion got people to believe in him but just in a different strain of religion.

Comment: (4) doesn't make sense because the GGs were *local* gods. They never claimed to be gods for other parts of the world. They were overpowered by Christianity which was a worldwide religion. No-one outside Greece ever worshipped the GGs.

Comment: Perhaps but who's to say that they had to reveal that they were other gods? My answers aren't based on fact of course because who know's if gods even exist in the first place? It depends on if the person is writing a historical based book or fantasy.

Comment: I wonder if there can be a god who doesn't believe in him/herself...

Comment: @chaslyfromUK If you have a look at classical Greek plays or legends, option 4 is not unrealistic at all. The Gods often entertained themselves by starting or ending wars, visiting beautiful women (or men) in countless different forms or holding competitions by manipulating humans into competing with each other. This could have been a competition to test the faith of humans that got out of hand, but in the end the Gods still won more worshippers.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK You're forgetting the Roman gods, which in principle were copied off the Greek gods but with Latin names (unless I'm mistaken)

Comment: 5) They're not the only pantheon around, and lost to the gods of the new religions, just like they ousted the Titans

Comment: (4) sound like good fun, exactly the kind of stuff greek deieties might make a sport out of.